# Change header in a4paper

Tags: header-footer

I want to write my master thesis and I use the following setting:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,  
    12pt,                               
    bibliography=totoc,     
    index=totoc,    
    abstracton,     
    headsepline,    
    %footnosepline, 
        ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{latexsym}           
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}  

\usepackage{subfig}     
\usepackage{float}      
\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{eurosym,bm,amsmath,amssymb,verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage [round,authoryear] {natbib} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic,lipsum}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{tocstyle} 
\usetocstyle{noonewithdot}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,hyperfootnotes=false,pdftitle=test, pdfauthor=test,pdfsubject=Project]{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings} 
\lstset{ 
  language=R,            
  basicstyle=\scriptsize,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},         
  commentstyle=\color{green},       
  stringstyle=\color{black}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------

\parindent0em           
\topmargin-20.4mm   
\textheight245mm

\textwidth157mm \oddsidemargin11mm \evensidemargin11mm

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\ifoot[]{My Name}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\hspace{16cm}
% {\includegraphics[scale=1]{Logowatermark.jpg}}}


\begin{document}    
\begin{titlepage}

%\hspace{2cm}\scalebox{1}{\includegraphics{Logo.jpg}}

\vspace*{1cm}
\large\textbf{Title}\\[0.5cm]

\normalsize description\\

subtext\\



Degree Course: enter here\\

\textbf{School of  \mbox{test}}\\[0.8cm]

Name of Chair \\[1.5cm]
%
%
\noindent\begin{tabular}[h]{@{}ll}
%\begin{tabular}{l l}
Chairholder:  \\
\\
Supervisors:             \\
\\
Author:   &My Name              \\
\\
%Address:         &               \\[0.2cm]
%                 &1                   \\
\\
Matriculation Number.:    &            \\
\\
Email:           &      \\
\\
\end{tabular}

\vfill
Place, Date

\end{titlepage}


\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}



\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onehalfspacing                 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

 % \input{Chapter1}  
%\newpage
%\input{Chapter2}
\newpage
\part{Description}
\section{Description}
test test test test test test
%\input{Chapter3}
\newpage
%\input{Appendix}
\newpage
\end{document}                                           % Ende des Dokuments
```

I am not happy with my header:
As you can see on the first page (roman number 1 ), there is no text in the header. So this would be only the case on the next page. But I want to have a header text on every page with the chapter description and with the section description.
Second I want to have at the left and at the rigth side of the black line of the header an additional vertical line. I attached a link to a screenshot which illustrates what I mean (I have not enough reputation to attach images :-( )

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) No need to add thanks in your post, we save space that way. Simply upvote any good answers you may receive to express your gratitude to those that help.

Comment: @Stat Tistician What you want to achieve is not very clear. You should clarify your original post so the community can guide you in the right direction. At any rate, the `fancyhdr` package is a very good package to customise header and footer. You should look it up.

Comment: @Jubobs 1. I want to have text in the header on every page including chapter and section description 2. I want to have a vertical line on the left and on the right side of the header, you can see it in the attached picture. I cannot implement fancyheader, since I get the following error message: ! LaTeX Error: Command \chead already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.